# Mapping COM interface method in JNA Invalid Memory Access exception

Tags: java, com, jna

I am using JNA to access the following [COM API](http://downloads.mapandguide.de/data/mgDevAPI/Docs/namespacemg_a_p_i.html). I have created this class which maps the " IMGApplication" interface of the API and some of the methods

```
public class IMGApplication extends Dispatch {
    private static final GUID IID_IMGApplication = new GUID("5FD5D92B-A4B6-4B32-AC3D-A6FF7AE83CD8");
    
    public IMGApplication() {

    }

    private IMGApplication(Pointer pvInstance) {
        super(pvInstance);
    }
    
    public static IMGApplication create(CLSID.ByReference clsIdByRef) {
        try {
            PointerByReference pointerByRef = new PointerByReference();
            
            HRESULT hres = Ole32.INSTANCE.CoCreateInstance(clsIdByRef, null, WTypes.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMGApplication, pointerByRef);
            if (COMUtils.SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
                return new IMGApplication(pointerByRef.getValue());
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public void minimize() {
        try {
            HRESULT hres = (HRESULT)this._invokeNativeObject(8, new Object[]{this.getPointer()}, HRESULT.class);
            COMUtils.checkRC(hres);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void maximize() {
        try {
            HRESULT hres = (HRESULT)this._invokeNativeObject(9, new Object[]{this.getPointer()}, HRESULT.class);
            COMUtils.checkRC(hres);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void setPosition(long x, long y, long width, long height) {
        try {
            HRESULT hres = (HRESULT)this._invokeNativeObject(11, new Object[]{this.getPointer(), new NativeLong(x), new NativeLong(y), new NativeLong(width), new NativeLong(height)}, HRESULT.class);
            COMUtils.checkRC(hres);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void shutdownMG() {
        try {
            HRESULT hres = (HRESULT)this._invokeNativeObject(12, new Object[]{this.getPointer()}, HRESULT.class);
            COMUtils.checkRC(hres);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void startMG(int startMode) {
        try {
            HRESULT hres = (HRESULT)this._invokeNativeObject(20, new Object[]{this.getPointer(), startMode}, HRESULT.class);
            COMUtils.checkRC(hres);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Main (it is a Lotus Notes Java Agent)

```
public class JavaAgent extends lotus.domino.AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {
        private boolean comWasInitialized = false;

        try {
            if(!COMUtils.comIsInitialized()) {
                Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(Pointer.NULL, Ole32.COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
            } else {
                comWasInitialized = true;
            }

            CLSID.ByReference clsIdRef = new CLSID.ByReference();
            HRESULT hRes = Ole32.INSTANCE.CLSIDFromProgID("mgAPI.mg_API", clsIdRef);
            COMUtils.checkRC(hRes);

            IMGApplication ComIMGApplication = IMGApplication.create(clsIdRef);
            
            ComIMGApplication.startMG(0); //<--- Works
                        
            ComIMGApplication.maximize(); //<--- Invalid Memory Access exception
            
            ComIMGApplication.minimize(); //<--- Invalid Memory Access exception
            
            ComIMGApplication.shutdownMG(); //<--- Invalid Memory Access exception

            ComIMGApplication.Release();
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(comWasInitialized == false) {
                if(COMUtils.comIsInitialized()) {
                    Ole32.INSTANCE.CoUninitialize();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked the COM API with the OLE/COM Object Viewer. The "IMGApplication" interface extends `IDispatch` and `IUnknown`.

So it has the 3 methods `QueryInterface`, `AddRef`, `Release` from `IUnknown` and the 4 methods `GetTypeInfoCount`, `GetTypeInfo`, `GetIDsOfNames`, `Invoke` from `IDispatch`.

[OLE/COM Object Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdmWR.png)

The `vtblId` of the first method (`BringToFront()`) in the "IMGApplication" interface has to be at index 7 and the last at index 21.

Unfortunately the only method that is working is `startMG()` (`vtblId` 20). On all the other methods i get the "Invalid Memory Access exception".

Comment: The [documentation for StartMG](http://downloads.mapandguide.de/data/mgDevAPI/Docs/group_____application.html#gaeb220183d84082ea6adb9ab94e18f36a) states for the `Mode` parameter:  Currently you can only use EMGStartMode "esmStandard", which is defined `mgAPI::esmStandard = 0`.  You are passing 1.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but potentially an issue, you are conditionally initializing COM but always uninitializing it, even if it's already initialized elsewhere. Only uninitialize if you successfully initialized.   Also unrelated, you should extend `Dispatch` rather than `Unknown`.  That shouldn't impact the errors you're seeing.

Comment: What is the return value for your `StartMG` call? Is it `INVALID_MODE` (-1610350590)?  If so you may not have actually started it.

Comment: Documentation for [MGStarted()](http://downloads.mapandguide.de/data/mgDevAPI/Docs/group_____client_events.html#ga7ee3d93f4bb2573ea9bab8d5cccc8ec7) says you should wait for it to be successfully started before passing other API requests.  You might be in a race condition trying to maximize it before it finishes initializing.

Comment: The `ComIMGApplication.startMG(1)` was a typo. In my program I pass the 0 as a parameter (i have corrected it in the code above). `startMG(0)` is working correct. When i call it, the program is starting.

I don't call all the functions one after the other of course. In my sample code I just wanted to show which methods are working and which does not.

The problem is, after the program is started and initialized completely, non of the other methods like `maximize()` or `minimize()` are working. I get the "Invalid Memory Access exception". Error.

Thank you!!

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested.

Comment: What I also noticed when I use `Ole32.COINIT_MULTITHREADED` instead of `Ole32.COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED` for `CoInitializeEx`, I no longer get "Invalid Memory Access exception". Then i get  "The server threw an exception. (HRESULT: 80010105)" and the value of HRESULT is "-2147417851"

Comment: Just noticed that "-2147417851" is the decimal value for 0x80010105 :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I just found the cause of the problem (thanks to the hint from Daniel with initializing). As soon as a Lotus Notes Agent is done running and is terminated, all instances are lost of course.  Every when I start the Agent again it is creating a new instance of the "mgAPI.mg_API".

```
        CLSID.ByReference clsIdRef = new CLSID.ByReference();
        HRESULT hRes = Ole32.INSTANCE.CLSIDFromProgID("mgAPI.mg_API", clsIdRef);
        COMUtils.checkRC(hRes);

        HRESULT hres = Ole32.INSTANCE.CoCreateInstance(clsIdByRef, null, WTypes.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMGApplication, pointerByRefDispatch);
        if (COMUtils.SUCCEEDED(hres)) {
            return new IMGApplication(pointerByRefDispatch.getValue());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
```

And of course i can not call any method other than `startMG(0)`, because in this instance the program is not running yet. That's why i got the "Invalid Memory Access exception"....

I tried this and it works, exactly as it should.

```
        if(!COMUtils.comIsInitialized()) {
            Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(Pointer.NULL, Ole32.COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
        } else {
            comWasInitialized = true;
        }

        CLSID.ByReference clsIdRef = new CLSID.ByReference();
        HRESULT hRes = Ole32.INSTANCE.CLSIDFromProgID("mgAPI.mg_API", clsIdRef);
        COMUtils.checkRC(hRes);
        
        PointerByReference pointerByRefUnknown = new PointerByReference();
        HRESULT hres = OleAuto.INSTANCE.GetActiveObject(clsIdRef, null, pointerByRefUnknown);
        
        IMGApplication ComIMGApplication = IMGApplication.create(clsIdRef);
        ComIMGApplication.startMG(0);
        
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
        
        ComIMGApplication.minimize();
        ComIMGApplication.shutdownMG();
```

Now I have to find out how to get an instance of the program if it is already running.

I tried it with `OleAuto.INSTANCE.GetActiveObject` but it did not work.

```
        if(!COM.COMUtils.comIsInitialized()) {
            Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(Pointer.NULL, Ole32.COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
        }

        CLSID.ByReference clsIdRef = new CLSID.ByReference();
        HRESULT hRes = Ole32.INSTANCE.CLSIDFromProgID("mgAPI.mg_API", clsIdRef);
        COMUtils.checkRC(hRes);
            
        PointerByReference pointerByRefUnknown = new PointerByReference();
        HRESULT hres = OleAuto.INSTANCE.GetActiveObject(clsIdRef, null, pointerByRefUnknown);
```

Comment: Your COM init is better than before, but checking whether it is initialized elsewhere leaves you at the mercy of whatever other app/thread initialized it and might uninitialize it while you're still using it!   It doesn't hurt to initialize it again to protect against this, but if you're trying a different mode it might fail.  [See how I've handled all these issues here](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/blob/38be67c7e81cdb884fab2581eca5c781f5c49fd3/oshi-core/src/main/java/oshi/util/platform/windows/WmiQueryHandler.java#L207-L254).

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. I think I will use it in my program as well. Thank you!